# Why does the US Marine Corps fly the Harrier, a VTOL or operationally STOVL aircraft?

Tags: military, aircraft-carrier, vtol, harrier, usmc

The UK flies the Harrier because they have [STOBAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STOBAR) carriers, but why does the United States Marine Corps fly the Harrier?

Comment: They also fly F-18's, which are not VTOL (they also fly F-35's) and other non-fighter aircraft.

Comment: Forward deployed close air support where long runways aren't available.

Comment: At the time this question is asked the UK has not operated Harriers for eight years,  has only one commissioned aircraft carrier, and that uses a STOVL configuration.  When the Royal Navy did operate Harriers they flew from carriers that also used the STOVL configuration.

Comment: Perhaps because the USMC doesn't have any aircraft carriers?  Not to mention that carriers aren't much use in places like Afganistan :-)

Answer (score 9):

Because when selecting aircraft the requirements were for close air-support and to be able to operate from amphibious assault ships like the [USS Tarawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Tarawa_(LHA-1)) and the [USS Nassua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Nassau_(LHA-4)).

These ships have very small decks that aren't geared towards launching larger aircraft like the F-18.